# Applescript Error with Spotify play command

Tags: applescript

I've started experimenting with writing apple scripts, and would like to interface with spotify, however it hasn't been playing nice. When I send commands from terminal such as

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Spotify" to play'
```

It returns the error: 30:34: execution error: The variable play is not defined. (-2753).

It doesn't seem to be a problem with any other applications, so I was wondering what could be causing this/how do I fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I'm basing most of this off of the shpotify script found here: https://github.com/hnarayanan/shpotify/blob/master/spotify
It doesn't run on my computer either, returning similar errors as above.

Comment: It works on my end...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this is what fixed it:

Go to the finder and type command+shift+g, then enter this:

```
/Applications/Spotify.app/Contents/
```

Then, double click on "Info.plist", edit the "Scripting definition file name" field value (on the right) so that it reads "applescript/Spotify.sdef" instead of "Spotify.sdef"

Save it, restart Spotify and it should work now.